# Conditional Redirect Using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a favorites button, for which if a non-logged user clicks, they should be redirected to the login page.

This button looks like this:

```
                <Button
                  onClick={() => addFavorite(card, props.loggedUser)}
                  color={
                    favorites.includes(card.id) ? "google plus" : "twitter"
                  }
                  icon={
                    favorites.includes(card.id) ? "heart" : "heart outline"
                  }
                />
```

I've tried several ways to create a conditional to redirect the user, but I'm having some issues.

I first tried this:

```
onClick={() => typeof props.loggedUser.id === "undefined" ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : addFavorite(card, props.loggedUser)}
```

this is what my loggedUser state looks like:

```
{token: undefined, firstName: undefined, id: undefined, favorites: undefined, username: undefined}
```

i believe this is correctly catching the first condition, as the addFavorite function isn't running, but it is not redirecting to the login page.

I've also experimented with props.push history, but I'm using redux, and when i tried to wrap my main App with withRouter, it was causing issues.  Not sure if I was doing it incorrectly, but I also was concerned about the other components having correct access to props.  I'm probably wrong on this, but either way, if there is a best way to accomplish this, i'm all ears.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manually redirect to a different route you need to use `history.push(url)` from the props that `react-router-dom` injects to the component.

If `props.history` is undefined you will need to wrap the component with `withRouter` HOC or use `useHistory`(hooks are available from V5.1) hook from `react-router-dom`

```js
const addFavorite = (card) => {
 if(!props.loggedUser.id) {
   props.history.push('/login')
   return
 }

 // add to favorites
}

<Button onClick={() => addFavorite(card)} />
```

Comment: thank you, and appreciate alerting me to useHistory hook--tried that and working great